# set properties before outlets in collectionViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

My goal is to set a `collectionViewCell` 's properties before its IBOutlets are set.
I tried to first set it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, like that :

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(Ids.Main.PollCell, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PollCell
        let image = contentImages[indexPath.row]
        let count = scores[image.associatedStack]
        let isBestScore = count == bestScore
        cell.associatedImage = image
        cell.bestScore = isBestScore
        cell.count = count != nil ? count! : 0
        return cell
    }
```

and then, when the outlet are set, I update their UI thanks to didSet :

```
@IBOutlet weak var image: DesignableImageView!{
        didSet{
            image.layer.cornerRadius = 35
            image.layer.masksToBounds = true
            if isCellSelected{
                image.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor()
            } 
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var countLabel: DesignableLabel!{
        didSet{
            countLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 7
            countLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
            if bestScore {
                countLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
            }
            countLabel.text = "\(count)"
            countLabel.hidden = !didVote
        }
    }
    var associatedImage: StackImage?
    var bestScore = false
    var didVote = false
    var count = 0
    var labelText = "0"
    var imageIsSet = false
    var isCellSelected = false
```

The problem is that the the outlets are set before the properties ! 
How is it possible ? 
How can I do to set first the properties and then from it set the outlets ? 
Is it because my cells are dequeued ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your cells are defined in InterfaceBuilder then the outlets will always be set in `awakeFromNib` which will be called before your code. `didSet` is almost certainly not the right place to be doing half the stuff you are doing. You should use it for the initial setup of the views that does not change between reuse.

Why not add `didSet` to things like `bestScore` where you can then configure as appropriate at those points?

```
var bestScore = false {
  didSet {
    if bestScore {
      countLabel.backgroundColor = .yellowColor()
    } else {
      countLabel.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()
    }
  }
}
```